# Can anyone explain the tp=1 process?

Tags: module, module-display

Can someone please explain the process behind tp=1 for the mod positions preview , 
I found the module output which is called from templates/system/html/module.php 
function `modChrome_outline(...)`

and I know that the style is being forced if site is accessed via tp=1 var https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/7d55d68cfbfe2b86589f2df9aab1771afce4fab0/libraries/cms/module/helper.php#L229

what I assume is happening is that when accessed via tp=1 the site is forced to use system template but I am looking for actual process and cant find it.

If here 
https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/7d55d68cfbfe2b86589f2df9aab1771afce4fab0/libraries/cms/module/helper.php#L231

I change

```
$attribs['style'] .= ' outline';
```

to

```
$attribs['style'] .= ' customoutline';
```

and have my customoutline chrome in modules.php I still get only the mods published on that page , not all module positions.

So can anyone please explain  or show me where( what file )  the process is located.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Found it , was missing one more override which was bellow

https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/7d55d68cfbfe2b86589f2df9aab1771afce4fab0/libraries/cms/module/helper.php#L98.

So to sum down ,

if u wish to make own mods preview

create your preview chrome in templates/your_template/html/modules.php

override module helper class ([see this](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/205/how-to-override-core-classes/324#324) ) by adding

```
    // my preview
    if ($app->input->getBool('myoutline'))
    {
        $attribs['style'] .= ' myoutline';
    }
```

here

https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/7d55d68cfbfe2b86589f2df9aab1771afce4fab0/libraries/cms/module/helper.php#L233

and extend this if statement
https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/7d55d68cfbfe2b86589f2df9aab1771afce4fab0/libraries/cms/module/helper.php#L98

with

```
 || $input->getBool('myoutline')
```

now you can control the modules positions preview from your template/html/module.php  and make it look better than what we have in j default since 1.0

access the preview via

```
sitename/?myoutline=1
```

**I will extend this one bit more and show you why I did this.**

In order for us to show users all available module positions for our [template framework](http://www.joomlatemplates.youjoomla.info/yougrids/grids-preview.html)

we must publish over 50 module positions which are just plain HTML. In my eyes this is an overload.

With the override in place , I can now remove all those 50+ modules and control the preview

and the content via the chrome function

http://prntscr.com/3im4yl

so I still have same preview like on our old demos

with much less modules.