# Can I use HTML overrides to override a file located in /components/administrator/componentname/helper/?

Tags: component, overrides

I know these are the core files of the component and I don't want to change them directly. So I'm looking for some way, like OpenCart's VQMod, to create an override, can I use HTML overrides for that purpose?

I have been to the component developer and they are not helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the **Helper** Class is loaded in a dynamic way, checking if it's already loaded, YES. You can override it.

Not with a HTML overrides, but with a **System Plugin**. You can create a System plugin, loading same **Helper** Class before the original one.

Please, check this related question:
[How to override core classes?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/205/how-to-override-core-classes)

Comment: This is great info thanks.  I had never thought to venture into developing a plugin but looking at the examples it looks relatively straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create overrides for the helpers files with the same way like the template overrides work.

But what you could do, with a template override, is that you can bypass the mvc pattern of the component and add any code you want in your custom view's file.

So for example you can create a template override for a specific view of the component, and in your template you can "talk" directly with the database and fetch the items you want, the way you want.