# Overriding a plugin's non-templated layout files?

Tags: component, overrides

I've been trying to figure out how to do this, but nothing seems to really work:

I want to override the results/pagination renderers from ZOOFilter which I know is in `/plugins/system/zoofilter/zoofilter/layouts/{search,_pagination}.php`, however it only appears that I can override templates?

The way that ZOOFilter is currently built is that it does not have any `/tmpl` directories in any of the plugin's locations within my installation, and obviously overwriting the plugin's code itself is more or less out of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To override zoofilter plugin: if you create your own system plugin with the same zoofilter class and it's loaded in order before zoofilter (you can even disable it), it should never be instantiated.

Comment: So would I have to make a copy of the plugin, or would I just make a system plugin that only contains the files that I want to override?

Edit: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/207/1670 That kind of sucks.

Comment: Both ways are valid. It's better if you include original files, you can re-use part of the original code, avoiding more code duplication.

Comment: I changed the question title to better reflect my issue. It seems I was mistaken earlier.