# How to override the mod_k2_tools helper function?

Tags: joomla-2.5, module, overrides, k2

I'm trying to understand how to override the helper.php found in */joomla_site/modules/mod_k2_tools* because it is not a component but a module, and it is not the controller, because the controller is mod_k2_tools.php.

If that above is right, then I have no idea how to override the helper.php to change the functionily of the K2 calendar.

I read [How to override core classes](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/205/how-to-override-core-classes), and followed the example [How to override the component mvc from the Joomla! core](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_component_mvc_from_the_Joomla!_core). However, nothing changed.

Before started with the override, I directly modified the */joomla_site/modules/mod_k2_tools/helper.php* to get the functionality I was looking for and as it worked, I decided starting with the override issue.

In the plugin that we must create, in the line

```
if('com_content' == JRequest::getCMD('option') && !$app->isAdmin())
```

the `com_content` makes reference to the content component, so, it should be replace by the 'mod_k2_tools` string, right?

Can the helper.php be overridden? Any guidance on what to check or pointing to a new beginning?

I'm using `Joomla! 2.5.27`, and `K2 2.6.8`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, not everything can be overriden, sometimes you can just create your own **mod_myk2_tools**.

Secondly, a feature can be overriden only if it is instantiated with a dynamic loading mechanism. This kind of technique checks if a resourse is already loaded before loading, allowing to load it before. In mod_k2_tools module, the helper is just included in this basic PHP way: "require_once (dirname(**FILE**).DS.'helper.php');". *It is not possible to override it.*

Comment: In the case of create the own `mod_myk2_tools` module, it is necessary change the name of the classes?

Comment: It seems it's not necessary. It works as you described. Now I can override the corresponding functionality.

Comment: If you create a new module, it is better to avoid name conflicts. Two classes with the same name cause a Fatal PHP Error.