# Override MVC classes in Joomla 3

Tags: joomla-3.x, plugin, overrides, mvc

Is there anyway to override MVC classes in Joomla 3?

I have found this thread but it is for Joomla 2.5. [How to override core classes?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/205/how-to-override-core-classes)

I have done MVC overrides in Joomla 2.5 successfully but now I have moved to Joomla 3. But that plugin not supported for Joomla 3.

I have found this article but I haven't good idea to write a plugin. Same concept has been used in the plugin which I used earlier in Joomla 2.5.

http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_component_mvc_from_the_Joomla!_core

And also can I extend those classes and overwrite methods?

Actually I want to override registration email template, user login task to check user type and profile view to retrieve more data from my tables.

I tried this plugin- https://github.com/phproberto/joomla-mvc-override
But it gives errors.

```
    Warning: fopen(D:\xampp\htdocs\my_project/libraries/legacy/module/helper.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\xampp\htdocs\my_project\libraries\joomla\filesystem\file.php on line 327
?>

    Fatal error: Class 'JModuleHelperLibraryDefault' not found in D:\xampp\htdocs\my_project\plugins\system\mvcoverride\core\module\helper.php on line 13
```

Is there anyone who faced this kind experience?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Funny, I just finished yesterday the implementation of this plugin in a site.

A fellow webdev and I modified it for joomla 3.x and it works.

It's here :
https://github.com/ghazal/plg_mvcoverride

It throws an error though when coupled with a nonumber.nl extension, 
Advanced Module Manager:

```
Call to undefined method JModuleHelper::addIncludePath()
```

Being in a hurry, my very unelegant solution was to comment out the first function :

```
    public function onAfterInitialise()
    {

    $moduleHelperContent = JFile::read(JPATH_LIBRARIES.'/cms/module/helper.php');
    $moduleHelperContent = str_replace('JModuleHelper', 'JModuleHelperLibraryDefault', $moduleHelperContent);
    $moduleHelperContent = str_replace('<?php','',$moduleHelperContent);
    eval($moduleHelperContent);
    jimport('joomla.application.module.helper');
    JLoader::register('jmodulehelper', dirname(__FILE__).'/module/helper.php', true);

}
```

and then, these 2 lines :

```
JModuleHelper::addIncludePath(JPATH_BASE.'/code/modules');
JModuleHelper::addIncludePath(JPATH_THEMES.'/'.$template.'/code/modules');
```

thus eliminating the possibility, in this case, to use it to override helper.php in a module.

I was about to post here to ask for help but you beat me to it.

Comment: Wow.. It works fine.. Thank you so much ghazal. I used a plugin before(Joomla 2.5) that you have mentioned in the document . Can you please update document? It would be helpful for others also. And also Can you add this in joomla extension directory please?

Comment: Done in github as you asked.
As for JED, it will take longer ...

Comment: Finally, Alex (Chartier) found a working solution for the error that I thought was related to Advanced Module Manager.
The original code was missing a line from the function it was overriding in jModuleHelper.
Alex also corrected the $path issue.

It's all been corrected in the github plugin.