# Override the Edit profile form allowing edit of contact fields

Tags: joomla-3.x, overrides, user, contact

Each user in my Joomla website has an associated contact, with photo, link, and bio (in the *miscellaneous information* field), etc...

I would like to override the edit profile page (`com_users/profile/edit.php`), disabling the *user profile fieldset*, and instead using a *contact profile fieldset*, with selected fields from associated contact.

How can I add those fields to the form in the `edit.php` file (and be sure that those fields will be actually updated on submit)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I would override the profile model with a plugin:**

https://community.joomla.org/blogs/community/521-did-you-know-overrides-are-not-just-for-html.html

https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_component_mvc_from_the_Joomla!_core

**Or alternatively overriding profile fields with plugin:** https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_profile_plugin

**Here is a similar question:**
[Override com_users model function save](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/12389/override-com-users-model-function-save)