# How to override helper file in template?

Tags: overrides, template-override

I did some modifications and added some extra functions in the file

```
/components/MY_COMPONENT/helper/MYFILE.php
```

What should I do to not lose these modifications in a future component update?

Comment: You mentioned "template" in your question title...was this a mistake? If you don't want to lose the changes you make, you'll have to create a plugin to extend the *helper.php* from the component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the **Helper** Class is loaded in a dynamic way, checking if it's already loaded, YES. You can override it.

Not with a HTML overrides, but with a **System Plugin**. You can create a System plugin, loading same **Helper** Class before the original one.

Please, check this related question: [How to override core classes?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/205/how-to-override-core-classes)