# helper file overrider is not working

Tags: joomla-3.x, overrides

I am trying to override the helper file of XYZ component and for this I have created a system plugin using these documentation -

> https://docs.joomla.org/J1.5:Plugin/Events/System

and

> [How to override core classes?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/205/how-to-override-core-classes)

My plugin is working fine and its giving me the values but only problem is - the plugin is loading before the component.

I am using *onAfterRoute* event for this and also tried some other events such as *onAfterInitialise, onAfterDispatch, onAfterRender*.

What should I do now to load my plugin after the component?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why onAfterRender is not working for you. Below is some alternate way.

Create your own custom plugin of custom type instead of system plugin say for example `customgroup`.

Once you installed your plugin, you can invoke your plugin using dispatcher.

```
JPluginHelper::importPlugin( 'customgroup' );
$dispatcher = JEventDispatcher::getInstance();
$results = $dispatcher->trigger( 'onMyEventName', array( &$param1, &$param2));
```

The above code will trigger `onMyEventName` in your plugin class `PlgCustomgroupSomeplugin`. Use this code at the end of request in your component.