# How to override an administrator template file that's included on the frontend?

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, template-override

A component is using `include` to load an administrator form in the front-end so users can fill it out and submit content.

I'd like to override that form, but it doesn't appear to be possible from my site template. I *can* override it from the administrator template (the default isis theme), but my changes can only be seen on the back-end.

Do overrides not carry over between templates? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overrides work based on the way layout files are called.

If it is hardcoded with an include, then it is not possible to override it in clean way.

I guess that at some level you could override the whole view. For instance, to replace ContentViewArticle, you can load your ContentViewArticle first with a system plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the insight Anibal. Would I use the system plugin to override a class like what's suggested [here](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/207/8455)? If so, I have another question. In the view.html.php file, there is the line `parent::display($tpl);`. Should I find a way to make $tpl always equal to the administrator template?

Comment: Yes, at the end, your are replacing and extending the original class.