# Override component class?

Tags: joomla-3.x

I've been googling this and haven't found anything that does the job. I have a component and I want to override some output text from the following location:

> administrator/components/com_mycomp/classes/myfile.class.php

I have tried the following to my template folder

> templates/mytemplate/html/com_mycomp/myfile.class.php
>   templates/mytemplate/html/com_mycomp/classes/myfile.class.php

But neither do the job, is there a way to achieve this? I'm probably doing something really stupid.

Thank you in advance

Donna

Comment: This Q/A may help you - make sure you review all the answers/comments and any links provided there.

Comment: @FFRewin - There is no reference to a Q/A - i know how to complete a standard override but the standard process does not seem to be working here, I am assuming because it is a class file? I could well be wrong.

Comment: oops sorry I forgot to put the link - [**How to override core classes**](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/205/how-to-override-core-classes)