# Overriding RssRenderer via plugin

Tags: plugin, overrides, rss

I have some issues with overriding the RssRenderer found in /libraries/Src/Document/Renderer/Feed/RssRenderer.php. In the past I have used a plugin to override a select html see topic here:

[Override JHtml core function select.radiolist](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/26806/override-jhtml-core-function-select-radiolist)

But I cannot seem to get it to work by changing the config.php to this:

```
<?php
/**
 * @package     Joomla.Plugin
 * @subpackage  System.Overrides
 *
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2012 Don Gilbert. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE
 */
define('OVERRIDES', dirname(__FILE__).'/overrides');

// Use JLoader to register all the classes you want to override
JLoader::register('RssRenderer', OVERRIDES.'/RssRenderer.php', true);
```

And then having in the overrides folder the RssRenderer.php copied with the changes I want:

```
<?php
/**
 * Joomla! Content Management System
 *
 * @copyright  Copyright (C) 2005 - 2020 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license    GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */

namespace Joomla\CMS\Document\Renderer\Feed;

defined('JPATH_PLATFORM') or die;

use Joomla\CMS\Document\DocumentRenderer;
use Joomla\CMS\Uri\Uri;

/**
 * RssRenderer is a feed that implements RSS 2.0 Specification
 *
 * @link   http://www.rssboard.org/rss-specification
 * @since  3.5
 *
 * @property-read  \Joomla\CMS\Document\FeedDocument  $_doc  Reference to the Document object that instantiated the renderer
 */
class RssRenderer extends DocumentRenderer
{
    /**
     * Renderer mime type
     *
     * @var    string
     * @since  3.5
     */
    protected $_mime = 'application/rss+xml';

    /**
     * Render the feed.
     *
     * @param   string  $name     The name of the element to render
     * @param   array   $params   Array of values
     * @param   string  $content  Override the output of the renderer
     *
     * @return  string  The output of the script
     *
     * @see     DocumentRenderer::render()
     * @since   3.5
     */
    public function render($name = '', $params = null, $content = null)
    {
        $app = \JFactory::getApplication();

        // Gets and sets timezone offset from site configuration
        $tz  = new \DateTimeZone($app->get('offset'));
        $now = \JFactory::getDate();
        $now->setTimeZone($tz);

        $data = $this->_doc;



        $url = Uri::getInstance()->toString(array('scheme', 'user', 'pass', 'host', 'port'));
        $syndicationURL = \JRoute::_('&format=feed&type=rss');

        $title = $data->getTitle();

        if ($app->get('sitename_pagetitles', 0) == 1)
        {
            $title = \JText::sprintf('JPAGETITLE', $app->get('sitename'), $data->getTitle());
        }
        elseif ($app->get('sitename_pagetitles', 0) == 2)
        {
            $title = \JText::sprintf('JPAGETITLE', $data->getTitle(), $app->get('sitename'));
        }

        $feed_title = htmlspecialchars($title, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');

        $datalink = $data->getLink();

        if (preg_match('/[\x80-\xFF]/', $datalink))
        {
            $datalink = implode('/', array_map('rawurlencode', explode('/', $datalink)));
        }

        $feed = "<rss version=\"1.0\" xmlns:atom=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom\">\n";
        $feed .= print_r($data);
        $feed .= "  <channel>\n";
        $feed .= "      <title>" . $feed_title . " Monkey</title>\n";
        $feed .= "      <description><![CDATA[" . $data->getDescription() . "]]></description>\n";
        $feed .= "      <link>" . str_replace(' ', '%20', $url . $datalink) . "</link>\n";
        $feed .= "      <lastBuildDate>" . htmlspecialchars($now->toRFC822(true), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') . "</lastBuildDate>\n";
        $feed .= "      <generator>" . $data->getGenerator() . "</generator>\n";
        $feed .= "      <atom:link rel=\"self\" type=\"application/rss+xml\" href=\"" . str_replace(' ', '%20', $url . $syndicationURL) . "\"/>\n";

        if ($data->image != null)
        {
            $feed .= "      <image>\n";
            $feed .= "          <url>" . $data->image->url . "</url>\n";
            $feed .= "          <title>" . htmlspecialchars($data->image->title, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') . "</title>\n";
            $feed .= "          <link>" . str_replace(' ', '%20', $data->image->link) . "</link>\n";

            if ($data->image->width != '')
            {
                $feed .= "          <width>" . $data->image->width . "</width>\n";
            }

            if ($data->image->height != '')
            {
                $feed .= "          <height>" . $data->image->height . "</height>\n";
            }

            if ($data->image->description != '')
            {
                $feed .= "          <description><![CDATA[" . $data->image->description . "]]></description>\n";
            }

            $feed .= "      </image>\n";
        }

        if ($data->getLanguage() !== '')
        {
            $feed .= "      <language>" . $data->getLanguage() . "</language>\n";
        }

        if ($data->copyright != '')
        {
            $feed .= "      <copyright>" . htmlspecialchars($data->copyright, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') . "</copyright>\n";
        }

        if ($data->editorEmail != '')
        {
            $feed .= "      <managingEditor>" . htmlspecialchars($data->editorEmail, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') . ' ('
                . htmlspecialchars($data->editor, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') . ")</managingEditor>\n";
        }

        if ($data->webmaster != '')
        {
            $feed .= "      <webMaster>" . htmlspecialchars($data->webmaster, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') . "</webMaster>\n";
        }

        if ($data->pubDate != '')
        {
            $pubDate = \JFactory::getDate($data->pubDate);
            $pubDate->setTimeZone($tz);
            $feed .= "      <pubDate>" . htmlspecialchars($pubDate->toRFC822(true), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') . "</pubDate>\n";
        }

        if (!empty($data->category))
        {
            if (is_array($data->category))
            {
                foreach ($data->category as $cat)
                {
                    $feed .= "      <category>" . htmlspecialchars($cat, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') . "</category>\n";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $feed .= "      <category>" . htmlspecialchars($data->category, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') . "</category>\n";
            }
        }

        if ($data->docs != '')
        {
            $feed .= "      <docs>" . htmlspecialchars($data->docs, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') . "</docs>\n";
        }

        if ($data->ttl != '')
        {
            $feed .= "      <ttl>" . htmlspecialchars($data->ttl, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') . "</ttl>\n";
        }

        if ($data->rating != '')
        {
            $feed .= "      <rating>" . htmlspecialchars($data->rating, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') . "</rating>\n";
        }

        if ($data->skipHours != '')
        {
            $feed .= "      <skipHours>" . htmlspecialchars($data->skipHours, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') . "</skipHours>\n";
        }

        if ($data->skipDays != '')
        {
            $feed .= "      <skipDays>" . htmlspecialchars($data->skipDays, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') . "</skipDays>\n";
        }

        for ($i = 0, $count = count($data->items); $i < $count; $i++)
        {
            $itemlink = $data->items[$i]->link;

            if (preg_match('/[\x80-\xFF]/', $itemlink))
            {
                $itemlink = implode('/', array_map('rawurlencode', explode('/', $itemlink)));
            }

            if ((strpos($itemlink, 'http://') === false) && (strpos($itemlink, 'https://') === false))
            {
                $itemlink = str_replace(' ', '%20', $url . $itemlink);
            }

            $feed .= "      <item>\n";
            $feed .= "          <title>" . htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($data->items[$i]->title), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') . "</title>\n";
            $feed .= "          <link>" . str_replace(' ', '%20', $itemlink) . "</link>\n";

            if (empty($data->items[$i]->guid))
            {
                $feed .= "          <guid isPermaLink=\"true\">" . str_replace(' ', '%20', $itemlink) . "</guid>\n";
            }
            else
            {
                $feed .= "          <guid isPermaLink=\"false\">" . htmlspecialchars($data->items[$i]->guid, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') . "</guid>\n";
            }

            $feed .= "          <description><![CDATA[" . $this->_relToAbs($data->items[$i]->description) . "]]></description>\n";

            if ($data->items[$i]->authorEmail != '')
            {
                $feed .= '          <author>'
                    . htmlspecialchars($data->items[$i]->authorEmail . ' (' . $data->items[$i]->author . ')', ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') . "</author>\n";
            }

            /*
             * @todo: On hold
             * if ($data->items[$i]->source!='')
             * {
             *   $data.= "          <source>" . htmlspecialchars($data->items[$i]->source, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') . "</source>\n";
             * }
             */

            if (empty($data->items[$i]->category) === false)
            {
                if (is_array($data->items[$i]->category))
                {
                    foreach ($data->items[$i]->category as $cat)
                    {
                        $feed .= "          <category>" . htmlspecialchars($cat, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') . "</category>\n";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    $feed .= "          <category>" . htmlspecialchars($data->items[$i]->category, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') . "</category>\n";
                }
            }

            if ($data->items[$i]->comments != '')
            {
                $feed .= "          <comments>" . htmlspecialchars($data->items[$i]->comments, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') . "</comments>\n";
            }

            if ($data->items[$i]->date != '')
            {
                $itemDate = \JFactory::getDate($data->items[$i]->date);
                $itemDate->setTimeZone($tz);
                $feed .= "          <pubDate>" . htmlspecialchars($itemDate->toRFC822(true), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') . "</pubDate>\n";
            }

            if ($data->items[$i]->enclosure != null)
            {
                $feed .= "          <enclosure url=\"";
                $feed .= $data->items[$i]->enclosure->url;
                $feed .= "\" length=\"";
                $feed .= $data->items[$i]->enclosure->length;
                $feed .= "\" type=\"";
                $feed .= $data->items[$i]->enclosure->type;
                $feed .= "\"/>\n";
            }

            $feed .= "      </item>\n";
        }

        $feed .= "  </channel>\n";
        $feed .= "</rss>\n";

        return $feed;
    }
}
```

It just doesn't take this override into consideration. If I make the changes directly in the core folder it changes. Does anyone know why this is not overriding? Maybe because it extends the class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the class is namespaced you have to use fully qualified class name:

```
JLoader::register('Joomla\\CMS\\Document\\Renderer\\Feed\\RssRenderer', OVERRIDES . '/RssRenderer.php');
```